# Can melted butter with food debris sit out at near room temp indefinitely?

Tags: food-safety

There's food debris in the butter. My knowledge says that the oxygen deprived liquid gets bacteria in it and it turns into botulism same as vacuum sealed individual bags of fish.

My bosses don't care and leave it like this every day. The bacon sits there indefinitely as well. No date. There's no timestamp on either butter or bacon.

[image]

Is this safe?

Comment: This is a food safty question catija

Comment: Then you need to remove the discussion of getting the health board to fix it. The health board is irrelevant to the question if all you care about is whether it's safe or not.

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear what you're asking. It's barely legible, and the only question mark in there isn't attached to a question.

Comment: @user57430 I've edited your question for you, but in the future we'd appreciate it if you'd try to put a little more time into it before you post, especially for things like spelling.

Comment: As for the answer, as far as I can tell there's nothing here that isn't covered by the linked duplicate - things left in the 40-140F ("near room temperature") range for more than 2-4 hours are unsafe. (Note that this is not purely because of botulism, and does not mean that things "turn into" botulism.)

Comment: Not a duplicate, IMO.  There are endless Google hits on butter, specifically, and whether it can be left at room temperature or not.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet But this isn't butter, this is butter *with stuff in it*.

Comment: With extra-italic *stuff*, some of which definitely is perishable and subject to the 2 hour rule ....

Comment: Whether or not this is safe (it very likely isn't) the idea of keeping either item around without so much as a date on it triggers every restaurant-trained horror I have. If your bosses don't care about this I would *hate* to see their walk-in cooler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. It might not be a very good idea to serve or eat it, though.

Check what the food debris is made out of - if anything forming debris in the butter is subject to the "2/4 hour in the danger zone" rule, it will still be subject to it when swimming in butter.

Comment: Bacon. Eggs. Asparagus. Brocoli pieces.  All small to tiny poeces but in there. The butter sits forblike 2 months in a tow not. They keep adding butter to it. It never gets changed